# How to optimize Visual Studio 2010 compile performance when run in a virtual machine?

Tags: optimization, compilation, virtual-machine, visual-studio-2010

It looks that Visual Studio 2010 compiles extremely slow when it is inside a virtual machine and the code is on a network share.

I cannot install it outside a virtual machine not I can keep the code on a local disk.

Current configuration data:

- host: OS X 10.7 Lion, 6GB RAM, 6 CPUs (not doing much other than running the guest)
- guest: Windows 7 Enterprise, 3GB RAM, 4 CPUs
- the huge codebase is located on network share on the guest

So, what can I co to improve the compilation speed?

Comment: What is your CPU? It it Core 2 or Core i7? What Virtual machine do you use (vmware, parallels, somthing else)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to me in slow access to sources (you can check this in task manager, if the total CPU load is << 100%  = even one CPU is not fully used). What kind of network share is used? How fast is network between Host and Storage (both bandwidth and latency).

You really should to put sources locally. You should try putting them on ramdisk or store on local disk.

The problem can be in the virtualizing solution. AFAIK, MSVC have command-line version, MSBuild http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx. May be it is possible to start msbuild from wine?

Comment: Do you have around ~30 GB of RAM to spare? Gigabit network is supposed to be faster than disk access.

Comment: The gigabit network itself is rather fast in terms of bandwidth, but even modern HDD with 7200 rpm can be faster (130MB/s) than GigE (125MB/s). SSD and 10k-15k RPM HDD are faster. The network protocol may be not so fast or latency can be big. Are 30 GB splitted into sub-projects of 100-200 MB? Is it 30 GB of hpp and cpp files?